# Hensel´s lemma for $p$-adic numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I would like to prove that $f(X) = X^2 + X + 2 \in \mathbb{Q}_2[X]$ has two roots in $\mathbb{Q}_2$. By applying Hensel´s lemma I have shown that $f(X) \in \mathbb{Z}_2[X]$ has two roots $\alpha \equiv 0\ mod\ 2$ and $\alpha \equiv 1\ mod\ 2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Can I use Hensel´s lemma in the same way for $2$-adic numbers ?

I know the following statement of Hensel´s lemma:

> If $f(X) \in \mathbb{Z}_p[X]$ and $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ satisfies $f(a) \equiv\ 0\ mod\ p$ and $f^{\prime}(a) \not \equiv 0\ mod\ p$, then there is a unique $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $f(\alpha) = 0$ and $\alpha \equiv a\ mod\ p$.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've shown that $f(a)\equiv0\pmod{2}$ for $a=1$ and $a=2$. To show that there exists some $\alpha\in\Bbb{Z}_p$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$, you can apply Hensel's lemma as you quote it in your question; it suffices to show that $f'(a)\not\equiv0\pmod{2}$ for some $a$.

Comment: Since $X^2+X+2 = X(X+1) + 2 \equiv X(X+1)\ mod\ 2$, I have shown it for $a=0$ and $a=1$. Using Hensel's lemma I have found two roots of $f(X) \in \mathbb{Z}_2[X]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Now if I assume that $f(X) \in \mathbb{Q}_2[X]$ can I just conclude that these roots are also roots in $\mathbb{Q}_2$ or do I need to prove anything else?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question. You can conclude this immediately, because $\Bbb{Z}_2$ is a subring of $\Bbb{Q}_2$.

Comment: No problem ;). Now you have answered my question. Thanks !